# Change the text in the selected box of a select menu onChange event

Tags: jquery, html, select

I have a select menu with option items as

```
<select>
<option>--1</option>
<option>--2</option>
<option>--3</option>
<option>--4</option>
</select>
```

When i select a item from the select menu, it displays **'--2'** in the box. I want only **'2'** to be displayed in the selected item box. How can i do that?

If i get a solution in jQuery, that would be more preferable.

Note: I don't want the values displayed in the drop down menu to be changed at any moment but the value that is displayed in the select box must not have the '--'(dashes).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you are trying to do is have a display value and a value that Javascript can read. In that case I propose you change your `select` element as opposed to writing custom javascript to change the appearance. This sounds like it may solve your problem.

I would write the `select` as per following:

```
<select>
    <option value="--1">1</option>
    <option value="--2">2</option>
    <option value="--3">3</option>
    <option value="--4">4</option>
</select>
```

then read the value instead of the text of the option element (see this: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_option.asp)

the solution you propose would be difficult to pull off using javascript or jquery unless you override the entire select with a custom element.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert("--1".replace("--", ""));
```

so:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    $("#someInput").val($(this).val().replace("--", ""));
});
```

[**Try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/KXpkM/)

Answer (score 0):

If want just to replace all entrys, you can call

```
$(function() {
    $('select').find('option').each(function(index,elem) {
        $(elem).text(function(i, text) {
            return text.replace(/^--/, '');
        });
    });
});
```

if you want to replace an entrys only when selected do

```
$(function() {
    $('select').bind('change', function() {
        var self = this;

        $(this).find('option:selected').text(function(i, text) {
            if( self.last )
                $(self.last).text(function(i, oldtext) {
                    return '--' + oldtext;
                });

            self.last = this;

            return text.replace(/^--/, '');
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: http://www.jsfiddle.net/4yUqL/39/